# HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, html-agility-pack, dom

This pertains to cookies set inside a script (maybe inside a script tag).

`System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` executes those scripts and the cookies set (like `document.cookie=etc...`) can be retrieved through its *Cookies* property.

I assume `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` doesn't do this (execution). I wonder if there is an easy way to emulate the `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` capabilities (the cookies part).

Anyone?

Comment: using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

Answer (score 3):

When I need to use *Cookies* and *HtmlAgilityPack* together, or just create custom requests (for example, set the `User-Agent` property, etc), here is what I do:

- Create a class that encapsulates the request/response. Let's call this class `WebQuery`
- Have a private *CookieCollection* (in your case **public**) property inside that class
- Create a method inside the class that does manually the request. The signature could be:

...

```
public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetSource(string url);
```

**What do we need to do inside this method?**

Well, using *HttpWebRequest* and *HttpWebResponse*, generate the http request manually (there are several examples of how to do this on Internet), create an instance of a `HtmlDocument` class using the constructor that receives an stream.

**What stream do we have to use?** Well, the one returned by:

```
httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

If you use *HttpWebRequest* to make the query, you can easily set the `CookieContainer` property of it to the variable you declared before everytime you access a new page, and that way **all cookies set by the sites you access will be properly stored in the `CookieContainer` variable you declared in your `WebQuery` class**, taking in count you're using only one instance of the `WebQuery` class.

Hope you find useful this explanation. Take in count that using this, you can do whatever you want, no matter if *HtmlAgilityPack* supports it or not.

Answer (score 2):

I also worked with Rohit Agarwal's [BrowserSession](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.de/2010/04/u) class together with HtmlAgilityPack.
But for me subsequent calls of the "Get-function" didn't work, because every time new cookies have been set.
That's why I added some functions by my own. (My solution is far a way from beeing perfect - it's just a quick and dirty fix) But for me it worked and if you don't want to spent a lot of time in investigating [BrowserSession](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.de/2010/04/u) class here is what I did:

The added/modified functions are the following:

```
class BrowserSession{
   private bool _isPost;
   private HtmlDocument _htmlDoc;
   public CookieContainer cookiePot;   //<- This is the new CookieContainer

 ...

    public string Get2(string url)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.UseCookies = true;
        web.PreRequest = new HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest2);
        web.PostResponse = new HtmlWeb.PostResponseHandler(OnAfterResponse2);
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
    public bool OnPreRequest2(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.CookieContainer = cookiePot;
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnAfterResponse2(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    private void SaveCookiesFrom(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        if ((response.Cookies.Count > 0))
        {
            if (Cookies == null)
            {
                Cookies = new CookieCollection();
            }    
            Cookies.Add(response.Cookies);
            cookiePot.Add(Cookies);     //-> add the Cookies to the cookiePot
        }
    }
```

What it does: It basically saves the cookies from the initial "Post-Response" and adds the same CookieContainer to the request called later. I do not fully understand why it was not working in the initial version because it somehow does the same in the AddCookiesTo-function. (if (Cookies != null && Cookies.Count > 0) request.CookieContainer.Add(Cookies);)
Anyhow, with these added functions it should work fine now.

It can be used like this:

```
//initial "Login-procedure"
BrowserSession b = new BrowserSession();
b.Get("http://www.blablubb/login.php");
b.FormElements["username"] = "yourusername";
b.FormElements["password"] = "yourpass";
string response = b.Post("http://www.blablubb/login.php");
```

all subsequent calls should use:

```
response = b.Get2("http://www.blablubb/secondpageyouwannabrowseto");
response = b.Get2("http://www.blablubb/thirdpageyouwannabrowseto");
...
```

I hope it helps when you're facing the same problem.

Comment: PS `public CookieContainer cookiePot;` needs to be `public CookieContainer cookiePot = new CookieContainer;`